# multiple sites file rights

Tags: nginx, security, php-fpm, shared-hosting

I spent more than an hour searching answers on the web but amazingly, none fit my problem.

I have a small dedicated server on which I host a few things. Mainly : an Owncloud Server and a few websites for me and my friends (mainly stuffs like Wordpress, MediaWiki...).

I use Nginx with different sites (one conf.d file per site).

For each site that needs php, I create a php-fpm pool.

For each site :

- I create a user : [website_user].
- I create a public_html directory in its home.
- If necessary, I give the user access to this directory via sftp.
- I configure the php-fpm pool to run under [website_user].
- I set every site's files to be owned by [website_user]:[nginx] user
- I set every site's files rights to 750

Is this good practice ?
Are there some flaws in this pattern ?

My Owncloud hosts some pretty sensitive informations (even though they are encrypted and it's "just" a private server : I'm no CIA or big company).

Should I run another Nginx server in chroot for Owncloud or is my setup secure enough ?

Comment: While not necessarily any particular standard; I give ownership of site webroots to the "servers" group. Then, at least 4 different sets of permissions. (A) Scripts which handle web requests and are called by routing rules -- execute & read (B) Static files, read only (C) Files which scripts can be used, but may not be executed themselves (such as templates, libraries, etc) and -- read only; write by owner (not group)  (D) web services which are for executing by direct path - -execute & read. I split project directories along these lines usually: composition, static, support and service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have things correct (running PHP-FPM pools under separate users), with a few exceptions.

Say your NGINX worker processes run as `nginx` and a PHP-FPM pool runs as `foo`.

From the top of your list downwards, the issues are:

> I set every site's files to be owned by [website_user]:[nginx] user

Wrong. If a PHP script creates some files (e.g. handling uploads), then the file might be owned by `foo:foo`. Subsequently, there is no guarantee that NGINX will be able to read it later.

So the best approach is having all files owned by `foo:foo` from the beginning.

Now the magic thing to do is having the user that runs NGINX worker processes *to be a member of `foo` user group*. Complicated? Not so:

```
usermod -a -G foo nginx
```

This is going to make `nginx` user to be in `foo` website user's group (supplementary). In other words, `nginx` user is now part of these groups: `nginx` and `foo`. The site user `foo` is a member of only `foo`.

For yet another website that will run under `bar` user in another PHP-FPM pool, you'll do the same: add `nginx` user to the user group of `bar`.

In this way, you can now very flexibly define what NGINX can see and not, by adjusting the group part of `chmod` settings.

If you want now you can have the least restrictive chmod and it would be `0750` for dirs and `0640` for files. Then NGINX can see everything and PHP-FPM can too. An easy way to set this across the site files:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o= /path/to/site/dir
```

I'm using `X` so that the executable (meaning traversal in the context of dirs) bit is set only on directories. Thus you end up with desired `0750` for dirs only while the files are `0640`.

But you can easily go more restrictive. Say, NGINX should not read `/config.php` because it solely read by PHP user and does not need to be "read" by NGINX, so you can easily do:

```
chmod 0600 config.php
```

And it will still work as desired.

If you're not doing any file existence checks in NGINX config (e.g. no `if (-f $request_filename) {`), then you can even set the same `0600` on every PHP file, or even `0400` for a lockdown config :) E.g. see my post on [Magento lockdown config](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/magento-chmod-1).

Comment: Thank you very much !
This is very helpful and clear.

Answer (score 0):

I take the liberty of adding something I find very interesting and that, weirdly, has bearly been covered on the web.

For a few years, it has been recommended to disable OPcache when doing shared-hosting using pools.
A well-known security issue was that OPcache allowed the PHP process of a pool to access another's pool files, even though the user had no rights on those files.

It turns out that this bug has been fixed but:

- It has not realy been publicized
- It is not enabled by the default settings.

So, if your PHP version is up to date (PHP7 < 7.0.14 and PHP5 < 5.6.29) you CAN safely enable OPcache in a shared-hosting pool environment as long as you add those options to your settings:

```
opcache.validate_permission=1
opcache.validate_root=1
opcache.use_cwd=1
```

Source : http://phpmagazine.net/2017/03/phps-long-standing-security-issue-with-opcache-leaking-sensitive-data-fixed.html